# How to dynamicly change between two animated Navigation Icons in toolbar appcompact v7 21

Tags: android, icons, toolbar, android-appcompat

One issue I have when trying to upgrade to appcompat v7 21's toolbar is I need to be able to change from a white animating hamburger and back arrow to a black animating hamburger and back arrow, depending on which fragment is in the activity.

I know I can't change the theme of the toolbar without having to restart the activity, so I'd rather use toolbar.setNavigationIcon( iconResource ) (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationIcon%28int%29) but I don't know where the animated icon's resource is located.

Here's my Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/toolbar_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tvToolbarTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here's the code to change the color:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mTvToolbarTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvToolbarTitle);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

...

private void setToolbarWhite(){
    mTvToolbarTitle.setTextColor(white); //Set Text White
    //mToolbar.setNavigationIcon( what Icon to use?? );
}

private void setToolbarBlack(){
    mTvToolbarTitle.setTextColor(black); //Set Text Black
    //mToolbar.setNavigationIcon( what Icon to use?? );
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!